# Embed Augmented Reality into a website

Tags: augmented-reality

I was just wondering if anyone knows whether it is possible to embed augmented reality into a website. So for instance, if I was to create a space invaders style game could I use put a placeholder image onto a website that comes to life and starts playing the game outside/around the computer when the users holds their phone up to the screen?

OR

Create a  website designed to be accessed on your mobile. And then when the user access the website, it accesses (with their permission) the users camera to turn their environment into the space invaders game. Critically I don't want to force the user to download anything but I can't find anything to support whether this is possible or not.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebGL](https://get.webgl.org/)+[Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/) for building Augmented Reality for a web page. For example like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naZQzDGGWEw).

Moreover, you can check this related [medium post](https://medium.com/archergroup/augmented-reality-in-the-browser-with-ar-js-86dafaca52f7). It can be helpful for you. This project was developed by a [Javascript framework for Augmented Reality](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js?utm_content=buffera07be&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer).